# C struct, variables with different bit sizes

Tags: c, struct, bit

I'm not sure how to create a Struct in C with its variables having different bit sizes, for example:

I want to create a struct with one variable as an 8-bit integer, one variable as an 16-bit boolean, one as an 8-bit boolean, one as a 32-bit floating point number etc.

I'm coming from java so all this is very confusing, thanks.

Comment: What does a 16-bit boolean look like in Java?

Comment: Are you asking about bit fields https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field or fixed width integer types https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer ?

Comment: What is your use case to have specific sizes?

Comment: @Inrin University

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
struct{
    float d; // By default 32 bits are initialized
    unsigned int a: 8;
    bool my_bool_8;
    bool my_bool_16; 
}nibble;

int main()
{
    printf("Size of structure is %lu\n", sizeof(nibble));
    printf("Size of my_bool_8 is %zu\n", sizeof(nibble.my_bool_8));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this small example response your question:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct {
    uint8_t my_int_8;
    int16_t my_bool_16;
    bool    my_bool_8;
    float   my_float;
} test;

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    printf("sizeof(my_int_8)=%zu\n", sizeof(test.my_int_8));
    printf("sizeof(my_bool_16)=%zu\n", sizeof(test.my_bool_16));
    printf("sizeof(my_bool_8)=%zu\n", sizeof(test.my_bool_8));
    printf("sizeof(my_float)=%zu\n", sizeof(test.my_float));
}
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Is there a page somewhere where i can see all the different lengths i can use?

Comment: `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from compiler and platform. For 8-bit integer, perhaps, you can use "int8_t" type. For 32-bit floating point - "float", but you must read documentation for your compiler.